# MySql update query not updating data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query which updates the last time a user logs in. For some reason, it is not updating the data when a user logs in. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {

$username_usr = $_POST["user_name"];
$password_usr = md5($_POST['password']);

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("logistor_logistor",$conn);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_usr WHERE username_usr='" . $username_usr . "' and password_usr = '". $password_usr ."'");
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(is_array($row)) {
$_SESSION["username"] = $row[username_usr];
$_SESSION["password"] = $row[password_usr];
$_SESSION["S_name"] = $row[name_usr];
} else {
$message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
}

if(isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
$query = "UPDATE user_usr SET logincounter_usr = logincounter_usr+1, lastlogin_usr = NOW() WHERE username_usr = '". $_SESSION["username"] ."'";
header("Location:user_dashboard.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: `$password_usr = md5($_POST['password']);` no no no!

Comment: Please use prepared statements.

Comment: Codesee yes yes yes ! I can take it from that you do not approve

Comment: maybe you need to execute the query with mysql_query($query) before sending the new location header? ;)

Comment: mysql_* functions are old and unsafe better move to mysqli_* functions or PDO MySQL... and read about SQL injections because this is possible within your code.

Comment: @Markus Thx that was it. If you want to set as answer I shall accept. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss execute the query in update

```
$query = "UPDATE user_usr SET logincounter_usr = logincounter_usr+1, lastlogin_usr = NOW() WHERE username_usr = '". $_SESSION["username"] ."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I just don't think we should be advocating the use of old and insecure code